# Eloquent query not returning the expected results from whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

**Current relationships:**

- A Clinic *hasMany* Consultants
- A Consultant *belongsToMany* Treatments (pivot table relationship)

A clinic may not have consultants, and a consultant may not have treatments. I only want to return clinics that `has` consultants, which `has` treatments, that includes a treatment that matches `$treatment_id` (hence the `has` existence check).

**Current attempt (which returns 0 results):**

```
clinic::whereHas('consultants.treatments', function ($query) use ($treatment_id) {
                $query->where('treatment_id', $treatment_id);
            })
        ->paginate(10);
```

I feel I require a `whereHas` within the `whereHas` function, to firstly determine if a consultant has treatments, but, if this logic is correct, how can I approach it within the function.

I am expecting 3 results to be returned, but currently it is 0.

How can I achieve this? Many thanks,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's many to many, it should be:

```
Clinic::whereHas('consultants.treatments', function ($query) use ($treatment_id) {
        $query->where('id', $treatment_id);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```